# Taylor-Remainder divided by $(x-x_0)^n$ goes to zero as $x$ approaches $x_0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

In a script about the Taylor-Theorem I'm reading I have stumbled across the property that for remainder $R_n(x,x_0): \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{R_n(x,x_0)}{(x-x_0)^n} = 0$. Since there are no further remarks or explanation, does anybody have any insight or hint on how I can understand this better?

Comment: This is known as Taylor -Young formula: with the notatiions of asymptotic analysis,  $\;R_n(x,x_0)=o\bigl((x-x_0)^n\bigr)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P_n(x)$ be $n$<sup>th</sup> order Taylor polynomial of $f$ about $x_0$. Then $P_n(x)$ is the only polynomial $P(x)$ of degree smaller than or equal to $n$ such that$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-P(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}=0.$$Now, use the fact that $f(x)-P_n(x)$ is precisely the remainder of order $n$.

Comment: How would you prove that theorem?

Comment: You will find a proof in Michael Spivak's *Calculus*, for instance. There, it's the corollary of theorem 3, from chapter 20.

Comment: Thank you, I found it! (+1)